# Unexpected behavior in a regular expression in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I created this regular expression and tested it out successfully

https://regex101.com/r/a7qvuw/1

However the regular expression behaves differently in this bash code that I wrote

```
# Splitting by colon
IFS=';' read -ra statements <<< $contents

# Splitting by the = sign.
regex="\s*(.*?)\s*=\s*(.*)\b"
for i in "${statements[@]}"; do
   if [[ $i =~ $regex ]]; then
      key=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} 
      params=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
      echo "KEY: $key| PARAMS: $params"          
   fi
done
```

The variable $contents has the text as is used in the link. The problem is that the $key has a space at its end, while the regular expression I tried matches the words without the space.

I get output like this:

```
KEY: vclock_spec | PARAMS: clk_i 1 1
```

As you can see there is a space between vclock_spec and the | which should not be there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: bash does not know `?` (non greedy).

Comment: Ahhhhhh. Ok. That makes sense. Any alternative, then? Or should I just trim the resulting string?

Comment: You may try `regex="\s*([^=]*\S)\s*=\s*(.*)\b"`

Comment: Thanks!! That worked. Someone should post the answer!!!

Comment: @Wiktor: do it.

Comment: `bash` may or may not support `\s` or `\S`, depending on the regular expression library present on your system (or possibly on how `bash` was compiled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Cyrus mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830914/unexpected-behavior-in-a-regular-expression-in-bash#comment76642408_44830914), lazy quantifiers are not supported in Bash regex. They act as greedy ones.

You may fix your pattern to work in Bash using

```
regex="\s*([^=]*\S)\s*=\s*(.*)\b"
           ^^^^^^^
```

The `[^=]*` matches zero or more symbols other then `=` and `\S` matches any non-whitespace (maybe `[^\s=]` will be more precise here as it matches any char but a whitespace (`\s`) and `=`, but it looks like `regex="\s*([^=]*[^\s=])\s*=\s*(.*)\b"` yields the same results).

Comment: If `\s` is not supported, use `[[:space:]]` instead. Instead of `\S`, then use `[^[:space:]]`